# Customizing layouts with CakePHP based on the current record

Tags: cakephp, layout, model, controller

Does anyone have recommendations on how to customize the layout sitewide based not on the current view, but the data associated with the view? In most cases, the models we are using have an associated Club id, so would have to customize the layout header image, css, etc, depending on which Club the current page is associated with.

Here is what I am thinking so far.
Call a function in the model associated with the current controller, which gives you the layout parameters.
In appController, beforeRender, set layout parameters for the club.

This doesn't seem very elegant, because each model would have to have this function, and how would I call the right model if beforeRender is defined in the app controller?

Some tips would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we ended up doing is checking in the app controller for the domain the site is currently being loaded from, then setting the layout based on this information (have a layout for each domain the site needs to look customized for). Not a great solution but it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Russel,

you might want to look at [this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/488/Themes).

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a file in layouts called "dashboard.ctp" then if your view is index, your function would be something like this...

```
    function index() {
    $this->User->recursive = 2;
            $this->layout = 'dashboard';
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
}
```

The important line being **$this->layout = 'dashboard';**